# Getting the result of a promise

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I'm trying to get my head round promises and so far it's very frustrating !

I am calling a method in the console that returns a promise like this :

```
getSharepointListItems("count")
```

The result of the call is :

```
Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: Array(1)
0: {ContentTypeId: SP.ContentTypeId, Title: "400000", _ModerationComments: null, File Type: null, ComplianceAssetId: null, …}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I want assign the `400000` to a variable and use it for further calculations, but im unable to capture it.

I read that i should chain a `.then` to my method call, which i understand also returns a promise. So i tried:

```
getSharepointListItems("PalletCounter").then( (r) => console.log(r))
```

And the result now is:

```
Promise {<pending>}
VM1315:1 
[{…}]
0: {ContentTypeId: SP.ContentTypeId, Title: "400000", _ModerationComments: null, File Type: null, ComplianceAssetId: null, …}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

So the `[[PromiseValue]]: Array(1)` has now been replaced by what looks like an object in an array, but there is also a promise which is `pending`, which i don't understand.I'm still unable to get to the 400000 value/result. Chaining more `.then` does not make a difference. I still get the above result.

How do i go about retrieving the result and saving it to a variable?

thanks

Comment: You can ignore the first line of the output you get (Promise pending), as evidently you are evaluating this in the console, which *also* outputs the value of the whole expression, which is the promise returned by the `then` call. It is of no interest to you since you just want the output of the explicit `console.log`. If this were a proper program (not in console), you would only see the output of `console.log`.

Comment: You can replace `console.log(r)` with `console.log(r[0].Title)` to get the "400000".

Comment: @trincot thanks, i tried that and it seems to work in the console, but a pending promise is also present. When i run it in the application, instead of 400000, i get [OBJECT PROMISE]

Comment: Make sure to go through the referenced question. It has all you need.

Comment: @trincot i will. thanks for the tip.